# jquery datetime pickers for selecting date hours and minutes

Tags: jquery, date, datetimepicker, hour, minute

i want to have a datetime picker of jquery to select the date, hours, and minutes. i want to have 12 hours clock which shows am-pm. and minutes selection. all plugins showing 24 hours clock and current time. i dont want to select the current time i should be able to select whatever the time i want.all plugins showing minutes step as 10 minutes or 15 minutes etc., i dont want this. i want to have time selection in 12 hrs format with am-pm and minutes selection from 1 to 59 minutes. i am unable to find this plugin. please help me.

Comment: visit this link you'll find the solution http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Could you share what you've tried so far? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a datetime picker based on bootstrap with am-pm option and time selection in 12 hrs format with tt too.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Minimum setup is the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course you must include the plugin and dependencies:

- jQuery
- Moment.js
- Bootstrap.js (transition and collapse are required    if    you're
  not using the full Bootstrap)
- Bootstrap Datepicker script
- Bootstrap CSS Bootstrap
- Datepicker CSS
- Locales: Moment's locale files

Answer (score 0):

Well most of those plugins probably have the option to set the minute step.
I don't know which plugins have you tried but [this](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) one has the option to set the minute step and lots of other options.